# How to set data in chart with interval?

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization

I use Google Chart API.

My array contents some parameters for displaying:

```
var rawData = [
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '03/02/13'}, 1],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '04/02/13'}, 2],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'05/02/13'}, 3]
];
```

How to display only one title for 3 element no all from array?

Comment: will you please clarify which _title_ you want to set? and on what _interval_??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the wording of the question, but I think you're looking for something like a [Data View](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView)? They allow you to filter a data table. Select only certain rows or columns, etc. If you only ever have the 3 rows you might also consider just having an array of 3 DataTables and cycling through them, redrawing the chart for each.